# how to change size of customView passed as UICalanderView Decoration?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I could not find much detail about how to add a customView as decoration for `UICalenderView`. There are many blogs telling how to add images but could not find anyone about `CustomView`. In images, we can return the decoration item with size parameter however in case of customView there is no option to pass size along with customView that you are adding. So in the end, I was able to add a view with red background, but the size is wrong. I tried to create a view and give it frame but it had no effect. So im confused how to adjust its size. Here is the method in which I add customView that im creating:

```
func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
   return .customView(addActivityCircle)
}
```

And this is my `addActivityCircle` method which for now just creating a view with red background color:

```
private func addActivityCircle() -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.clipsToBounds = false
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        return view
    }
```

When I run this code I do see a view with red color but it's like a small rectangle, not 50x50. If I pass small values like 20x20, I do see a small rectangle but anything above that I see a rectangle of fixed size. I think that's the limit of decoration item but in apps like Fitness app by apple, there are bigger activity rings than that so there should be a way to have bigger sized custom views as this is just too small. The width is fine but the height is just too less. This is what im getting and it does not get any higher than that:
[image]